# Generator only returns the next value if __next__() is called explicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class defined that holds the data necessary for its generator function, as well as the generator itself:

```
class LinkedEncs():
    def __init__(self, ref_ids, all_encs, max_encs=3, data_len=7, front_trim=3):
        self.ref_ids = ref_ids
        self.all_encs = all_encs
        self.max_encs = max_encs
        self.data_len = data_len
        self.front_trim = front_trim
        self.ref_num = 0  
        self.cur_ref = self.ref_ids[self.ref_num]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            self.cur_ref = self.ref_ids[self.ref_num]
            self.ref_arr = np.hstack((np.zeros((365, 1)), np.empty((365, int(self.max_encs * self.data_len)), dtype=np.object)))
            self.ref_num += 1
            matched_rows = self.all_encs.loc[self.all_encs['ref_id'] == self.cur_ref]
            for _, row in matched_rows.iterrows():
                self.ref_arr[row['days_ago']][0] += 1
                day_n = self.ref_arr[row['days_ago']][0]
                col_shift = self.data_len * (day_n - 1) - 2
                if self.ref_arr[row['days_ago']][0] > self.max_encs:
                    continue
                for i in range(self.front_trim, self.front_trim + self.data_len):
                    self.ref_arr[row['days_ago']][i + int(col_shift)] = row[i]    
            self.ref_num += 1
            yield self.cur_ref, self.ref_arr
        except(IndexError):
            print('end of list')
```

My understanding is that the correct way to load the data and get the generated values is to use `next()`, like this:

```
linked_enc_generator = LinkedEncs(ref_enc_ids, linked_encs)

while True:
    try:
        print(next(linked_enc_generator))
    except(StopIteration):
        print('done')
        break
```

But that doesn't work. Instead, it results in an infinite loop that returns `<generator object LinkedEncs.__next__ at 0x0000019B9DB7C3C8>` over and over.

What *does* work is replacing `next(linked_enc_generator)` with an explicit call of `__next__()`:

```
while True:
    try:
        print(next(linked_enc_generator.__next__()))
    except(StopIteration):
        print('done')
        break
```

Also, it doesn't seem to matter whether I have an `__iter__` function or not, which doesn't match my understanding either.

What's going on here?

Comment: Your `__next__` function returns a generator... it is a generator function. That's what you wrote it to do.

Comment: Short answer: `return self.cur_ref, self.ref_arr` instead of `yield ...`, see the duplicate for more details.